# How do I check the horizontal or vertical image status in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, react-native

I want to use the 'contain' feature when the vertical image comes and the 'stretch' feature when the horizontal image comes in the react-native. How do I check the horizontal or vertical status?
For example:

```
<Image resizeMode={status==horizantal?'contain':'stretch'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this in a conditional rendering function and would figure out the size using the static `getSize` method from the `Image` class like this :

```
buildImage = (imageUri) => {
   Image.getSize(imageUri, (width, height) => {
      if (width > height) {
         //image is horizontal
         return [<Image resizeMode={'contain'}/>];
      } else {
         //image is vertical
         return [<Image resizeMode={'stretch'}/>];
      }
   });
   return [];
}

render() {
   return(
      {this.buildImage(this.state.image)}
   )
}
```

[getSize Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#getsize) for reference.